# How to use OfficeUI Fabric global typography rules with officeui fabric react app?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I'm troubled regarding using fabric typography in a react application.

I want to build an app that looks like fabric.

How to get typography rules ?

Especially, I want `<h1>`,`<h2>` tags to looks fabric headers.

I tries to import the css from my global layout component, but headers are still raw.

```
import 'office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css';
```

I also tried to reference the CDN css file using

```
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css"
    />
```

But still without success.

[Edit]Please note that within components styles are applied. For example, a `h1` tag within a `Dialog` component will show as expected.

[/Edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the typography defined in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/typography, make sure you place the correct class names for the header you want. And make sure you wrap the html with `ms-Fabric`. If you are using react, `<Fabric>` does that for you too.

For example:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css">

    <body class="ms-Fabric">
       <h1 class="ms-font-xl">Hello World</h1>
       <h1 class="ms-font-su">Hello World</h1>
    </body>
```

There are two ways to include the Fabric Core.

1. Via CDN, Example CDNs are https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css or https://unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react@6.119.0/dist/css/fabric.min.css (use a prod ready cdn)
2. Via NPM, Once you `yarn add office-ui-fabric-react` or `npm install office-ui-fabric-react` in your `index.css` or `index.sass` just import it. Webpack will make sure it packs everything correctly.

   **css:**
   `@import '../node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.css';`

   **sass:**
   `@import '../node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/Fabric';`

   **Note:** This will bring all fabric styles (which is the only way), later on, the Fabric team stated they will create components instead of doing this.

That's all

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me to the right direction. I was able to mimic what I wanted by *defaulting* headers behaviors with sass rules like `h1 {
    @extend .ms-font-su;
}`. this way all h1 behaves as I expected